# PHP - Save first page visit date with cookie

Tags: php, date, cookies

I need to save the first page visit date (+ 1 day) with a cookie so the generated date (first visit date + 1 day) can be used dynamically for another jQuery script. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you seem to have posted this already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746031/add-cookie-to-countdown-timer

Comment: Not really, you read wrong. Anyway, can you help?